# How to access the cookies database of firefox when firefox is running with python?

Tags: python, cookies

I want to access the cookies programmatically which are stored in the cookies database on the filesystem. I tried to use [this code](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/88611952815b56b5b8b5), but it either gives a message

```
database is locked
```

when the browser is running, or does not yield any results when the browser has been quit (I assume all cookies are removed on the filesystem then?).

How can I programmatically access all cookies related to a browser session with python? I want to have a script that e.g. lists all the cookies on a terminal. How to do that? (Can be either chrome or firefox).

Comment: Firefox only stores _non-session_ cookies to `cookies.sqlite`, so you won't be able to access those cookies with the script you linked to. Non-session cookies are those that don't have an expiry date. If you restart your browser, it won't remember them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [the code](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/88611952815b56b5b8b5) you provided as a reference and it seemed to work when I did put manually the path to my cookies and made some minor changes to make the code work on Python 3.8. Are you running as Admin your cmdprompt (or sudo in terminal if Linux/Mac) ?

Basically you should be able to scrape the data you want from `mydata` after line 47 in [the code](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/88611952815b56b5b8b5) and just print them out.

Comment: I get the same error: `Database is locked` even when running the command as `sudo` on the command line on a Mac. Probably it's because its a Mac.

Comment: Try to exit the browser. Check that it is really closed and does not have a dot under the browser icon in your taskbar. If it does right click and "Exit" or similar. After that try again.

Comment: But when I exit the browser, most/all cookies are deleted! This is not what I want. I want to access the cookies from all active browser tabs!

Comment: I tried the script also on Linux with python 3.8 and it worked. Are you using python 2 or 3 ? You could try change the file permissions on that cookie.sqlite also.

Comment: I am using python 3.8.

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of the file instead of reading it directly?

Comment: I get an empty list. Seems nothing is in  the 500 kB large file!

Comment: Tried it locally with `sqlite`: The code I linked is incorrect!!!

Comment: The table does not have any URL values!

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have mentioned, I removed everything after line 48 and just printed the `mydata` to display results.

Comment: It works for a copied sqlite, but ultimately I want to read and modify cookies while in use in the browser!

Comment: Why do you need to read and modify cookies? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that? You _might_ be able to do it one of two ways: 1. write a Firefox plugin that exfiltrates all the cookies, or 2. attach a hook that exfiltrates all the cookies to one of Firefox's functions, or otherwise read Firefox's memory which stores, somewhere, all the cookies. You can't really do either of those directly with Python. Keep in mind, at this point, you're effectively writing spyware.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because that Firefox uses SQLite to obtain an EXCLUSIVE lock on the database ([link](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode))

the solution is to make a backup copy of the database befor read it